# Deserialize matching types from different assemblies

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, assemblies

If I have a class/interface pair defined in `AssemblyA` under namespace `AssemblyA.Entities`:

```
public IEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public Entity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I serialize it to XML using `XmlSerializer`:

```
var myEntities = new List<IEntity>();
// myEntities is populated somehow
var data = XmlSerializationManager.Serialize(myEntities);
// 'data' gets saved to disk somewhere as a file
```

*Then*, if I duplicate the code/namespaces into `AssemblyB` so that I have namespace `AssemblyA.Entities` and the exact same code:

```
public IEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public Entity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I attempt to deserialize the previously serialized XML, will I get back `AssemblyB`'s list of `AssemblyA.Entities.IEntity`? Or will it fail?

At what point does the serializer stop caring about what it's deserializing to? Can the assembly differ? Can the namespaces differ? Do the type names matter so long as the properties are named the same?

Comment: You can look for the _fully qualified type names_ in the serialized text. If they're there, the info about the assembly is persisted on serialization by that particular serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. You will get AssembyB entity.

This is essentially how Web services work when the client would scaffold classes based on information in the wsdl, the client would then deserialise the data from the soap message into these scaffolded classes.